# Delete table OrderItem from Database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

Ok for start :
I am doing Pharmacy project in Spring. I'm using Eclipse and Database PostgreSQL.

In database i have table name :OrderItem,CustomerOrder,Product and Register(this is class with pass and info about user).

Ok i want to delete CustomerOrder with given id.

```
co.deleteCustomerOrder(co.getCustomerOrder(id));
```

If i done this i had error like this :

**Details: Key(orderid)=(1421007984736) have call in table "orderItem"
Error: modification or delete on table "customerorder" Violates the foreign key "        fk60163f61b0099af4 " table " orderitem "**

So i added this one in first place

```
 cos.deleteOrderItem(cos.getOrderItem(id))
```

then

```
co.deleteCustomerOrder(co.getCustomerOrder(id));
```

and now i have error like this :

**HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create delete event with null entity**

Maybe there is problem with some entity classes: Register or other.By the way when i delete with PgAdminIII  orderItem then of course i dont get first error and i can done this line of code

```
   co.deleteCustomerOrder(co.getCustomerOrder(id));
```

normally.

****How to resolve this second  error ?. I dont want to use PgAdmin xD****

Some of my code .

```
package app.Spring.domain;



import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomerOrder")
public class CustomerOrder {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "orderID")
        private long orderID;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
        private Register register;

        @Column(name = "status")
        private String status;

        @Column(name = "totalCost")
        private float totalCost;

        @Column(name = "orderDate")
        private Date orderDate;

        public CustomerOrder() {
        }

        public CustomerOrder(long orderID, Register register, String status,
                        float totalCost, Date orderDate) {
                this.orderID = orderID;
                this.register = register;
                this.status = status;
                this.totalCost = totalCost;
                this.orderDate = orderDate;
        }

        public long getOrderID() {
                return orderID;
        }

        public void setOrderID(long orderID) {
                this.orderID = orderID;
        }

        public Register getRegister() {
                return register;
        }

        public void setRegister(Register register) {
                this.register = register;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
                return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
                this.status = status;
        }

        public float getTotalCost() {
                return totalCost;
        }

        public void setTotalCost(float totalCost) {
                this.totalCost = totalCost;
        }

        public Date getOrderDate() {
                return orderDate;
        }

        public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
                this.orderDate = orderDate;
        }
}



package app.Spring.domain;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "OrderItem")
public class OrderItem {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "itemID")
        private long itemID;


        @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
        private Product product;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
        private CustomerOrder customerOrder;

        @Column(name = "quantity")
        private int quantity;

        public OrderItem() {
        }

        public OrderItem(long itemID, Product product, CustomerOrder customerOrder,
                        int quantity) {
                this.itemID = itemID;
                this.product = product;
                this.customerOrder = customerOrder;
                this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public long getItemID() {
                return itemID;
        }

        public void setItemID(long itemID) {
                this.itemID = itemID;
        }

        public Product getProduct() {
                return product;
        }

        public void setProduct(Product product) {
                this.product = product;
        }

        public CustomerOrder getCustomerOrder() {
                return customerOrder;
        }

        public void setCustomerOrder(CustomerOrder customerOrder) {
                this.customerOrder = customerOrder;
        }

        public long getQuantity() {
                return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
                this.quantity = quantity;
        }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/users")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

    @Autowired
    RegisterService reg;

    @Autowired    
CustomerOrderService co;
    @Autowired
OrderItemService cos;     

 @RequestMapping("/removecustomer/{id}")
    public String removeCustomerOrderById(@PathVariable Long id) {

        System.out.println("remove  customerOrderID "+id);
      cos.deleteOrderItem(cos.getOrderItem(id));
    co.deleteCustomerOrder(co.getCustomerOrder(id));


        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

CustomerOrderService

```
public class CustomerOrderImpl implements CustomerOrderService{


    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }    

  @Override
      public CustomerOrder getCustomerOrder(Long id) {
          return (CustomerOrder)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(CustomerOrder.class.getName(), id);
      }

 public void deleteCustomerOrder(CustomerOrder v) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(v);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
        }


}
```

OrderService

```
public class OrderItemImpl implements OrderItemService {



    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }    



    public OrderItem getOrderItem(Long id) {
        return (OrderItem)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(OrderItem.class.getName(), id);

    }
public void deleteOrderItem(OrderItem v) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(v);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cos.deleteOrderItem(cos.getOrderItem(id));
co.deleteCustomerOrder(co.getCustomerOrder(id));
```

Each record (row) in a table has a key. You are using the same key to delete items in two different tables.

Unless they happen to be in a One-to-One relationship, the id of the records do not reflect the relationship. In this case, you are trying to delete an order item using a key that is not recorded.

To put it bluntly:

- You want to delete customerOrder 16;
- You cannot delete customerOrder 16; because it has orderItems 4 & 5 related to it due to a foreign key.
- You are trying then to delete order item 16; which does not exist (second error).

The proper solution is either:

- Set the relationship from customerOrder and orderItems to delete in cascade `(cascade = {CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.MERGE})`
- Before deleting `customerOrder`, find the related `orderItems` and delete them (again, the key of the different elements will not be related).

If you are having issues understanding the concepts of keys, foreign keys and cascading, you should first learn more about how SQL does work.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved :)

change method that delete and change some code for find related orderItems.Ty for you anwser i should learn some more SQL.This CascadeType.Remove wasnt needed.

```
public void deleteOrderItem2(OrderItem orderItem) throws Exception {
      Session session=null;
      Transaction tx=null;
      try {
            session =     sessionFactory.openSession();
              tx=session.beginTransaction();
              orderItem = (OrderItem) session.merge(orderItem);
              session.delete(orderItem);
              session.flush();
              tx.commit();
      } catch (PersistenceException pe) {
              tx.rollback();
              throw pe;
      } finally {
              session.close();
      }
```

}